# How custom role(of Lambda) works with EC2 role policy?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-iam, aws-sam

Below is the custom execution role(`some-role-serv-LogicalID-GDGGGGGBMW2`) created for lambda function(`AWS::Serverless::Function`) written using SAM template:

```
{
  "permissionsBoundary": {
    "permissionsBoundaryArn": "arn:aws:iam::111222333444:policy/some-permission-boundary",
    "permissionsBoundaryType": "Policy"
  },
  "roleName": “some-role-serv-LogicalID-GDGGGGGBMW2”,
  "policies": [
    {
      "document": {
        "Version": "2012-10-17",
        "Statement": [
          {
            "Action": "sqs:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:111222333444:someq*",
            "Effect": "Allow"
          },
          {
            "Action": [
              "logs:CreateLogGroup",
              "logs:CreateLogStream",
              "logs:PutLogEvents"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:logs:us-east-1:111222333444:log-group:*",
            "Effect": "Allow"
          }
        ]
      },
      "name": "lambda-policy",
      "type": "inline"
    }
  ],
  "trustedEntities": [
    "lambda.amazonaws.com"
  ]
}
```

---

Where `some-permission-boundary` is:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "logs:CreateLogGroup",
                "logs:CreateLogStream",
                "logs:PutLogEvents"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:logs:us-east-1:111222333444:log-group:*"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
        },
        {
            "Action": [
                "sqs:DeleteMessage",
                "sqs:ReceiveMessage",
                "sqs:SendMessage",
                "sqs:ListDeadLetterSourceQueues",
                "sqs:GetQueueAttributes",
                "sqs:GetQueueUrl"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:111222333444:someq*"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
        }
    ]
}
```

---

`some-role-serv-LogicalID-GDGGGGGBMW2` is assigned a permission boundary(`some-permission-boundary`) in SAM template

Lambda function assumes custom role with below SAM template syntax:

```
Role: !GetAtt LogicalID.Arn
```

---

Amidst deployment,

lambda is created(using `sam deploy`) from a docker container within EC2,

where is an additional role policy(below) is assumed by EC2:

```
   {
        "Condition": {
            "StringEquals": {
                "iam:PermissionsBoundary": "arn:aws:iam::111222333444:policy/some-permission-boundary"
            }
        },
        "Action": [
            "iam:CreateRole",
            "iam:AttachRolePolicy",
            "iam:PutRolePolicy",
            "iam:DetachRolePolicy",
            "iam:GetRolePolicy"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:iam::111222333444:role/some-role*"
        ],
        "Effect": "Allow"
    }
```

---

This EC2 policy is supposed to make sure that any custom role(say `some-role-serv-LogicalID-GDGGGGGBMW2`) that does not have below property:

`PermissionsBoundary: !Sub "arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:policy/some-permission-boundary"`

should not allow creating role `some-role-serv-LogicalID-GDGGGGGBMW2`

I get below error while stack creation:

### [image]

Stack is created successfully but,

1) 
Why `sam deploy` command gets this error?

2)

Does the EC2 policy disallow custom role(`some-role-serv-LogicalID-GDGGGGGBMW2`) creation that comes without permission boundary(`some-permission-boundary`)? as expected...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error states that your EC2 instance, entity that is calling `sam deploy` action does not have permissions to perform `iam:GetRolePolicy` which really is the case here.

Problem is that while you can restrict the other 4 actions with this condition

```
"Condition": {
    "StringEquals": {
        "iam:PermissionsBoundary": "arn:aws:iam::111222333444:policy/some-permission-boundary"
    }
}
```

You can't do the same for `GetRolePolicy`. This actions can't be restricted by that condition otherwise its effect is nullified. The only service level condition applicable to this action is `iam:ResourceTag`.

If you go to management console and try to create such IAM policy, you can see this warning caused by combination of your condition with `iam:GetRolePolicy` action.

> This policy defines some actions, resources, or conditions that do not
>   provide permissions. To grant access, policies must have an action
>   that has an applicable resource or condition.

Solution is to split your statement into two. First with that condition to restrict creation of IAM Roles that do not have necessary permission boundaries together with the other IAM actions except of the mentioned `iam:GetRolePolicy`. Then you should create second statement containing just `iam:GetRolePolicy` without that condition.

```
    {
        "Condition": {
            "StringEquals": {
                "iam:PermissionsBoundary": "arn:aws:iam::111222333444:policy/some-permission-boundary"
            }
        },
        "Action": [
            "iam:CreateRole",
            "iam:AttachRolePolicy",
            "iam:PutRolePolicy",
            "iam:DetachRolePolicy"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:iam::111222333444:role/some-role*"
        ],
        "Effect": "Allow"
    }
```

and

```
   {
        "Action": [
            "iam:GetRolePolicy"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:iam::111222333444:role/some-role*"
        ],
        "Effect": "Allow"
    }
```

And to answer your second question. Yes, you can use `iam:PermissionsBoundary` condition key together with `iam:CreateRole` to prevent roles without a specific permission boundary from being created.

Comment: I still don't get, why getRolePolicy should be without condition... Because, this action is raised by role(`some-role`)

Comment: 1. You can't use `aws:PermissionBoundary` with `createPolicy`. It wouldn't make much of a sense either. 2. Because it was designed that way and because it is just a read action, you are not modifying anything by using this action so there is not much of a use for such condition. You can restrict its scope by specifying `resource`.

Comment: yes it does not make sense to use `aws:PermissionBoundary` with policy  because we only have an option to create role with permission boundary in SAM template, which would suffice